# Discrete MCMC JAGS chains get stuck

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, bugs

I have been running a model where one of the parameters is discrete. I can't think of a simple way to represent this model, so I won't (unless necessary) post it here.

My issue is, that when I look at the chains, I can see that chains tend to get stuck in local maxima in discrete space. This means that the chains do not mix, and I am left with ugly, bimodal or trimodal distributions. From an examination of likelihood space, I know that the actual distribution should be much smoother.

Any idea what this might signify in the model? I suspect it is due to parameter covariance, but I am not sure how to test/remedy this.
Any ideas would be most welcome!

Edit: please see the model below. There are two discrete parameters $d$ and $Tp$, and two continuous ones, $lambda$ and $nBase$.

Sorry for its complexity; I couldn't think of a simpler example that demonstrated its properties:

```
model {
for (i in 1:NTotal) {
    for (j in 1:30)
    {
         for (k in 1:36)
         {
              A[i,j,k] <- equals(k,d[villageID[i]])*step(Tp[villageID[i]]-j)*(Tp[villageID[i]]-j+1)*rain[captureDays[i]-j+1-d[villageID[i]]]
         }
     }
     captureNumber[i] ~ dpois(nu[i])
     nu[i] <- 0.04*roomsSampled[villageID[i]]*(lambda[villageID[i]]*(2/(Tp[villageID[i]]*(Tp[villageID[i]]+1)))*sum(A[i,,])
+ nBase[villageID[i]])
     }
for (j in 1:NVillages){
     lambda[j] ~ dlnorm(0,10)
     nBase[j] ~ dlnorm(0,10)
     indD[j] ~ dcat(punif[])
     indDm[j] ~ dcat(punifm[])
     Tp[j] <- xDm[indDm[j]]
     d[j] <- xD[indD[j]]
     }
for (k in 1:35)
{
    punif[k] <- 1
    xD[k] <- k + 4
}
for (k in 1:27)
{
    punifm[k] <- 1
    xDm[k] <- k + 4
}

}
```

A indicative read out from plotting the samples for $d$ is shown below:

[image]

Notice that there is no mixing of the chains for the first case. For the other ones, I can't even see the other chains.

Best,

Ben

Comment: Other than proving broad tips, I am not sure we'll be able to help you with you more details. The distributions you are sampling from might be part of your problem. Also, are the parameters that are failing to converge latent or observed variables? At the very least, would you be able to post your traceplots and an algebraic summary of your model?

Comment: @RichardErickson - thanks for your tips in terms of presenting the question. I have added the model above, along with diagnostic plots. Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you modeling? `captureNumber` makes me think ecology but `village` variables make me think people.

Comment: @RichardErickson - haha. You are right - it's mosquitoes. We have data at the village level on the numbers...

Comment: I think you're model is having trouble because it might be bimodal (or you don't have enough data to determine what it should be). I had similar problems when I used `JAGS` in grad school for population modeling of _Daphnia_. I would suggested reading [Bayesian Population Analysis Using WinBUGS](http://store.elsevier.com/Bayesian-Population-Analysis-using-WinBUGS/Marc-Kery/isbn-9780123870216/). They got their `JAGS` code somewhere on the web. Personally, I've switched over to [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/), but the principles from the book still hold true.

Comment: @RichardErickson - thanks. I do actually have that book (will give it a look), and already use Stan. (I am not using Stan here because of the discrete parameters). Thanks for the tips though. Best, Ben